# How to extract sections of Jenkins pipeline script into classes?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, refactoring, jenkins-pipeline

I want to refactor my Jenkins pipeline script into classes for readability and reuse.

The problem is i get exceptions when doing so.
Let's look at a simple example:

When i run

```
echo currentBuild.toString()
```

everything is fine

But when i extract it into a class as so:

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {
    def runBuild() {
        echo currentBuild.toString()
    }
}
new MyClass().runBuild()
```

i get an exception:

```
Started by user admin
Replayed #196
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: currentBuild for class: MyClass
```

What is the proper way of extracting pipeline code in to classes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are on the right way, but the problem is that you didn't pass the script object to the instance of your class and was trying to call method which is not defined in the class that you have created.

Here is one way to solve this:

```
// Jenkins file or pipeline scripts editor in your job
new MyClass(this).runBuild()

// Class declaration
class MyClass implements Serializable {
    def script
    MyClass(def script) {
        this.script=script
    }
    def runBuild() {
        script.echo script.currentBuild.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your kind answer.
I figured it out a few minutes after posting the question :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with latest pipeline plugin v2.5. Following exception is thrown
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: script for class: MyClass`

Comment: @bram could you please provide us more details of your script?
Now do you run it?

Answer (score 3):

your code missing declare class field **script**

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {

    def script

    MyClass(def script) {
        this.script=script
    }

    def runBuild() {
        script.echo script.currentBuild.toString()
    }
}
```

this code should be ok @bram